# ¿Cómo publicar con Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects un instalador que instale la app en un único archivo .exe sin sus .dll y otros archivos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, instalacion, .net-5, publish

Me gustaría publicar una aplicación con Visual Studio 2019, que he desarrollado en Windows Forms con .NET (C#). Lo que ocurre es que al publicar el instalador de la misma (utilizo la extensión propia de Microsoft para producir el instalador llamada "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects"), y al instalar la aplicación con el instalador que me produce, me guarda el .exe junto con muchísimos archivos .dll para que esta se ejecute. ¿Es posible hacer que el archivo .exe ya contenga los .dll y que tan solo se produzca así un archivo final único?

Comment: Por motivos de licencias es posible que no puedas incorporar todas las dlls en tu aplicación. Una DLL de terceros es una porción de código de la que no eres autor y sin embargo usas ... deberías revisar las licencias de todas las librerías que estás usando antes de hacer esa pregunta

Comment: Gracias @eferion. ¿Y eso cómo puedo hacerlo? Por ejemplo, la mayoría de mis dll son para Entity Framework Core, ¿cómo podría revisar las licencias de esas librerías?

Comment: Eso que mencionas te sucede porque tu proyecto tiene *referencias* a esas librerías, en vez de *contener* dichas librerías. Si añades las librerías al proyecto directamente en vez de referenciarlas, deberían ir incluidas en él. Aunque nunca usé installer projects, imagino que funcionará igual que otros.

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B!! ¿Y como se pueden añadir en vez de referenciar?

Comment: La verdad es que no recuerdo el proceso exacto, pero a grandes rasgos, debes añadir la librería como *resource* al proyecto y luego añadirla desde la carpeta donde la hayas puesto (dentro de tu proyecto). Seguro que alguien con más experiencia en esto puede decirte exactamente cómo hacerlo... pero googleando un poco deberías encontrarlo también

Comment: Si se puede publicar como unico archivo tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Para publicar tu proyecto en un unico Archivo, puedes hacer de dos maneras, CLI o visual studio:
Para hacerlo por CLI, deberias modificar tu archivo de proyecto y colocar la propiedad `PublishSingleFile` en `true`

En el ejemplo veras las propiedades para este tipo de aplicacion:

PublishSingleFile: habilita la publicación de un solo archivo.

SelfContained: determina si la aplicación será independiente o dependiente de la plataforma.

RuntimeIdentifier: especifica el sistema operativo y el tipo de CPU que tiene como destino.
PublishTrimmed: habilita el uso del recorte de ensamblados, que solo se admite para aplicaciones independientes.

PublishReadyToRun: habilita la compilación Ahead Of Time (AOT). (Si no me equivoco, esto hace que tu archivo sea mas pesado, pero arranca mas rapido)

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Luego por consola parado en tu directorio del proyecto.

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true
```

y la otra manera seria:

1: Boton derecho sobre el proyecto -> publicar

2: Editar tu configuracion de publicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Ramiro Barone!! Lo único yo estoy utilizando Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects para que me genere un instalador de mi proyecto. Y el instalador, cuando me instala la aplicación no me produce un único archivo .exe, sino el .exe con muchos archivos .dll. En realdiad ese era el problema. Poder tener únicamente el .exe, en vez de tantos .dll (o que solo sean unos pocos).

Comment: Claro, ese es el comportamiento normal.

Comment: Y @Ramiro Barone, ¿no habría forma de que eso no ocurriera?

Comment: hace mucho no uso ese metodo, y uso click once, para publicar y actualizar las app de manera automatica. Por algun motivo particular usas esa forma de crear y no la que te pase?

Comment: La verdad es que nunca he usado Click Once, y no se utilizarlo muy bien. Por otro lado, necesito generar un instalador para exportar el proyecto si o si de esa manera, y no se si Click Once puede hacer eso... Aun y todo muchas gracias!!! :D

Comment: la forma que te di es la mas facil de crear un instalador. Click once solo debes subir tu instalador a un ftp y luego tu app buscara version nueva y si la encuentra instala la nueva version. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019

Comment: usa la segunda opcion que te pase, haciendole click derecho a tu proyecto principal y coloca `Publicar`